# How to get steamID from Steamworks API in Unity3D in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, steam, steamworks-api

I'm coding a game in C# in unity3d. I installed the Steamworks API, and now I see that a lot of things like `getPersonaName()` and avatar need SteamID to fetch them. I want to know how, even if it's the briefest of explanation, just point me in the right direction.

P.s: on their support page is a link to documentation. In that documentation are the examples for getting your name and names of your "friends", but the examples use CSteamID variable, which declaration is unknown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to call:

```
SteamUser.GetSteamID();
```

Comment: I got it to work, but I don't know how to change id.getMediumAvatar() into Texture in unity3d?

EDIT: Don't know how to do <code> tags.

Comment: That sounds like the kind of thing that you should create a new question for, rather than nesting it in the comments on this one.

Comment: Created a new one :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709536/how-to-use-id-getsmallavatar-unity3d-with-steamworks